# How to investigate MySQL errors

Tags: mysql, database, error-handling

Below is a query I found to display my errors and warnings in MySQL:

```
SELECT 
`DIGEST_TEXT` AS `query`,
`SCHEMA_NAME` AS `db`,
`COUNT_STAR` AS `exec_count`,
`SUM_ERRORS` AS `errors`,
(ifnull((`SUM_ERRORS` / nullif(`COUNT_STAR`,0)),0) * 100) AS `error_pct`,
`SUM_WARNINGS` AS `warnings`,
(ifnull((`SUM_WARNINGS` / nullif(`COUNT_STAR`,0)),0) * 100) AS `warning_pct`,
`FIRST_SEEN` AS `first_seen`,
`LAST_SEEN` AS `last_seen`,
`DIGEST` AS `digest`
FROM
 performance_schema.events_statements_summary_by_digest
WHERE
((`SUM_ERRORS` > 0) OR (`SUM_WARNINGS` > 0))
ORDER BY
 `SUM_ERRORS` DESC,
 `SUM_WARNINGS` DESC;
```

Is there some way to drill down into performance_schema to find the exact error message that is associated with the `errors` or `warnings` above?

I was also curious what it means if the `db` column or `query` column shows up as `NULL`. Below are a few specific examples of what I'm talking about

```
+---------------------+--------+------------+--------+----------+--------+
|       query         |   db   | exec_count | errors | warnings | digest | 
+---------------------+--------+------------+--------+----------+--------+
|  SHOW MASTER LOGS   |  NULL  |    192     |  192   |    0     |   ...  |
+---------------------+--------+------------+--------+----------+--------+
|        NULL         |  NULL  |   553477   |   64   |  18783   |  NULL  |
+---------------------+--------+------------+--------+----------+--------+
|  SELECT COUNT ( * ) |  NULL  |     48     |   47   |    0     |   ...  |
|FROM `mysql` . `user`|        |            |        |          |        |
+---------------------+--------+------------+--------+----------+--------+
```

I am also open to using a different query that someone may have to display these errors/warnings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message will be in `performance_schema.events_statements_history.message_text` column. You do need to make sure that `performance_schema_events_statements_history_size` config variable is set to a positive and sufficiently large value, and that the history collection is enabled. To enable the history collection, run:

```
update performance_schema.setup_consumers set enabled='YES' 
where name='events_statements_history';
```

To check if it is enabled:

```
select * from performance_schema.setup_consumers where 
name='events_statements_history';
```

`NULL` value of `db` means the there was no active database selected. Note that the active database does not have to be the same as the database of the table involved in a query. The active database is used as default when it is not explicitly specified in a query.

This will only give you error messages, not warning messages. From a brief look at the code it appears that the warning text does not get logged anywhere - which is understandable given that one statement could produce millions of them. So you have a couple of options:

- Extract the statement from `events_statements_history.sql_text`, re-execute it, and then run `SHOW WARNINGS`
- Extract the statement, track it down in your application code, then instrument your code to log the output of `SHOW WARNINGS` in hopes of catching it live if manual execution fails to reproduce the warnings

Comment: Will turning this on significantly affect system performance?

Comment: I have not benchmarked it, but I would roughly anticipate a slowdown of no more than 3%. The actual number will depend on your workload. You can use `sysbench` to get a rough idea, and (better) your own application-specific benchmark to measure the impact.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I was able to turn it on, and it does tell my there are warnings, but no sort of warning code or anything to determine what the actual warnings are. Is there somewhere else that these associated warnings are stored?